# API for gathering gitlab CI job execution statistics?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a self-hosted gitlab enterprise server (11.2.3-ee), and run CI builds for C++ in docker images.  There is a pool of runners on different physical hosts, and for the most part, any job can be scheduled on any runner.  The physical hosts are not identical--some are faster than others.

The admin section provides a way to view statistics at a *job* level. The admin page on the server (at https://gitlab.example.com/admin/jobs) shows this, but I cannot find anything in the API.  I've tried looking in [the source](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/tree/master/) but am not familiar enough with the organization to have found anything yet.

Is there API access for job stats across the entire instance (not just project level)?  Or, am I constrained to scraping the admin screen?

Comment: So far no luck finding anything, although I've successfully employed https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cli.html as a way to gather statistics for a single runner using the gitlab runner API https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/runners.html#list-runner-s-jobs